# How to use elements of a vector with index in sigma?

Tags: matlab

I need to use sigma in MATLAB but I face an error:

```
X = [1 2];
syms k;
sum = symsum (X(k),k,1,2)
```

Actually I have to use the elements of a vector inside a sigma, in a FOR LOOP, when `k` changes.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: the output should be the summation of the first and second elements of the vector X. one plus two equals to three. I have to write the code in this manner, because later on, I need to use index k in a FOR loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variant without using symbolic math:

```
X = [10 20];
k = [1:2];
sum(X(k));
```